# Rails: Verify correct user across multiple controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, user-controls, refactoring, controller

I have several controllers that require a correct user for their edit/update/delete actions.  What is the Rails-way to accomplish the following:

Currently, in each controller I have the following code:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :correct_user, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  # normal controller code

  private

  def correct_user
    @foo = Foo.find params[:id]
    redirect_to some_path unless current_user == @foo.user
  end
end
```

I have similar code in 3 controllers.  I started to bring it out to a helper like this:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def correct_user( object, path )
    if object.respond_to? :user
      redirect_to path unless object.user == current_user
  end
end
```

But I'm wondering if this is a good way to do it.  What's the accepted way to solve this?

Thank you

**EDIT**

The correct user check here is because I want to make sure it's only the author who can make edits/deltes to each of the objects.

To clarify, the objects would be things like Questions and Posts.  I don't want to use something like CanCan as it's overkill for something simple like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really like using RyanB's CanCan, which allows you to both restrict access to actions based on the user, and centralize such authorization into basically a single file.

- CanCan on GitHub: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan
- Screencast explaining how to setup/use it: http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan

**EDIT**

No problem. I hear you on CanCan - it takes a little while to get up and running on it, but it's designed to do exactly what you're asking - per object authorization.

**Alternative:**
Another way to do this is move your authoriship/current_user check to the `ApplicationController` class, from which all of your other Controllers inherit (so they will get that code through inheritance - and you don't need to write the same code in multiple Controllers), and it would look something like...

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...

  helper_method :correct_user

  private
    def correct_user( object, path )
      redirect_to path unless object.user == current_user
    end

end
```

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified better in my post. Please see post for update.

Comment: I've updated my answer per my best understanding of your updates.

Comment: can I just clarify, do you still then call this in your child controllers as a before_filter or differently? And if so how do you set object and path?

Comment: Hey @christian - let me see if I can remember after almost two years. I believe the `object` parameter here is meant to represent the resource that the controller action is loading. For example, if it's a blog and you're loading the `posts/:id/edit` action the object would be an instance of the `Post` class. Then the `path` object is the path you want to redirect to if the `current_user` logged in is **NOT** a user that is authorized to perform that action. For example, if an unauthorized user is trying to edit a post, maybe you just redirect them to `posts/:id/show` with a flash message.

Comment: As far as when/where to call it, you could do it in a `before_filter` if appropriate, or since it's just a helper method you could call it inside the controller action itself.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following :

```
def edit
  @foo = current_user.foos.find(params[:id])
end
```

This way, only if the current user is the owner of the `Foo` he will be able to see it.